# Only the first order in jquery works and the rest is not

Tags: jquery

The first order in the script only implemented while the rest doesn't work, it was working but I did some changes and currently the rest doesn't, i really appreciate your help with this, the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#freeze1").on("click", function() {
            $("#login").toggle("2000");
        });
        $("#main").on("click", function() {
            $("#login").hide();
        });
        $("#freeze").on("click", function() {
            $("#login").hide();
        });
        $("#freeze").on("click", function() {
            $("#contact").toggle("2000");
        });
        $("#main").on("click", function() {
            $("#contact").hide();
        });
        $("#freeze1").on("click", function() {
            $("#contact").hide();
        });
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#top').fadeIn();
            };
            else {
                $('#top').fadeOut();
            };
        });
        $("#top").click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, "slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I think it can be a simple error within the code but maybe because I have been trying for so long on the code I can't seem to see it, Thanks.

Comment: What does and doesn't work? and what changes have you done? You don't need double document-ready handler

Comment: Is this line `};else {` won't produce an error?

Comment: The first order on #freeze1 is the only working

Comment: nothing produce error

Comment: why do you have two on click of #freeze.. why not put the other toggle to the first 1..